# Editing hdfs-default.xml in HDP cluster using ambari UI

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have a HBase cluster built using Hortonworks Data Platform 2.6.1 and I want to edit some properties in hdfs-default.xml.

Can we edit hdfs-default.xml using ambari UI?

If we edit the file manually in all nodes which services do we need to restart?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but Ambari won't edit the defaults file, it edits the `hdfs-site.xml`, and you will need to restart at least every HDFS client and service to make the changes take affect.

Do not manually edit files on disk - Ambari will overwrite them on the next service restart

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 I want these changes to be done in my hdfs-site.xml 
 -https://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/560/60/small-cluster-limitations. So do you think adding them in hdfs-site.xml is also fine?

Comment: You can set these in Ambari via the custom hdfs-site section. Again, do not edit files manually